# How to make Entity Key Mapping in Entity Framework like sql's foreign key?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I try to give entity map on my entity app. But how can I do it? I try to make it like below:

```
var test = ( from k in Kartlar where k.Rehber.....
```

above codes k.(can not see Rehber or not working ) if you are correct , i can write k.Rehber.ID and others. i can not write:

```
from
 k in
 Kartlar
where
k.Rehber.ID = 123 //assuming that navigation property name is Rehbar and its primary key of Rehbar table is ID
&& k.Kampanya.ID = 345 //assuming that navigation property name is Kampanya and its primary             //key of Kampanya table is ID
&& k.Birim.ID = 567 //assuming that navigation property name is Birim and its primary key of Birim table is ID
select
k
```

images you can see: [alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/9334/test1f.png](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/9334/test1f.png)

also: You should look : http://i42.tinypic.com/2nqyyc6.png

I have a table it includes 3 foreign key field like that:

My Table: **Kartlar**

- ID  (Pkey)
- RehberID  (Fkey)
- KampanyaID  (Fkey)
- BrimID (Fkey)
- Name
- Detail

How can i write entity query with LINQ ?

```
select * from Kartlar where RehberID=123 and KampanyaID=345 and BrimID=567
```

BUT please be careful I can not see RehberID, KampanyaID, BrimID in entity they are foreign key. I should use entity key but how?

Comment: i try to do this: (from k in genSatisCtx.Kartlar where k.RehberReference.EntityKey == RehberID select k);

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Web.UI.MobileControls;


namespace EfEntity
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)<br>
            {
                gwKampanya.DataSource = Kart(297688, 88689, 68686);
                gwKampanya.DataBind();
            }
        }

        public List<Kartlar> Kart(int RehberID, int KampanyaID, int BrimID)
        {
            List<Kartlar> kartlar;
            using (xyzEntities genSatisctx = new xyzEntities())
            {
                kartlar = (from k in genSatisctx.Kartlar
                           where k.Rehber.ID == RehberID &&
                                 k.Kampanya.ID == KampanyaID &&
                                 k.Birim.ID == BrimID
                           select k).ToList();

                return kartlar;

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: It looks like the model the user has will have navigational properties and if he uses those in the grid this could cause an issue with lazy loading killing performance.  If this is the case the OP should use eager loading.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102647/Select-N-1-Problem-How-to-Decrease-Your-ORM-Perfor.